# Magento 2. Indexers sometimes switch(on their own) to Update On Save when configured on Update On Schedule

Tags: magento2, indexer

My issue is simple enough. It reproduced on 2 separated projects.

I have all indexers set on Update on Schedule. Without anyone changing them, I just wake up with them configured with Update On Save.

Any thoughts on the matter/possible issues are highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue as you. They just switch to update on save. I've made sure that the command indexer:set-mode can't be used to switch them, and I have Amasty's admin logger, which will log any attempt to do it via the backend. 

I'm buffled at this. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: I noticed this is happening during setup:upgrade but I'm not sure which script is channgin them :(

Comment: Could you check if this is the case for you as well? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33386

Comment: @gabtzi we don't really run s:u on the server, s:u is executed once at deploy on the machine on which the build is done and the issue is non-deterministic, at least not based on deploys. In other words the issue does not reproduce after a release/deploy and we only run s:u during a new release process.

Comment: I see. Then it's definitely a similar but different issue. Probably something else is triggering it. You could try the same approach as I did and put a CHECK CONSTRAINT on the db so that when something tries to change a specific indexer's mode, it will throw an exception. That exception will be logged then.

Comment: some result from that? We have same issue.